# compare 2 select in mysql According to result number

Tags: mysql, select

how to compare results of two query in my sql an first show that query have more result i tried some hours but i could not

```
SELECT COUNT(fileproperty_tbl.`Value`='aaaa') as c1
FROM fileproperty_tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(file_tbl.`Name`='mohsen324') as c2
FROM file_tbl
```

that is my code and i know this is wrong

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What result are you looking for?

Comment: i am creating search progrom i want write word and my program run select query and search in varius coulmns to find my words